# Infer function prop input type typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a component (called Container) which has a renderHeader prop. The type of this prop is

```
(input: {
    scrollY: Animated.Value
    onLayout: (e: LayoutChangeEvent) => void
    headerHeight: number
  }) => JSX.Element
```

I have two ways to pass the prop. Either pass an inline arrow function or declare it somewhere and pass its name as prop.
In the second one Typescript does not automatically infer the function's argument types. As there are several other props, using inline arrow functions make the code messy and less readable.

How can I use the approach below and make TS infer the function's argument types?

```
const renderHeader = ({ /* This argument's type should be inferred without explicitly defining it  */ }) => {}
<Container renderHeader={renderHeader} />
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can't infer that for you, you'll have to tell it something.

One way that may be less clunky that providing the event type after the destructuring is to assign a type to the `renderHeader` constant. Provide yourself a utility type:

```
type LayoutChangeHandler = (e: LayoutChangeEvent) => void;
```

and then use it when creating the function:

```
const renderHeader: LayoutChangeHandler = ({/*...*/}) => {
    // ...
};
```

TypeScript will infer the argument type from the function type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECkFcGcBdQIajggdgEwLQEtUC4AoWATwAcBTUAGQWIHtJYBhACzQHNyBRAN3NXgBeUAG8CoCcjoBbcrBa52eZLABOigNzjJaOvPKqAKgtRLQqSNIBGBrQF8CRMpRr1GrDuQASadABsDUGEACnJlVwZmNlNuPgEASiCAPlAeOmx0LQIAYzpUOFBVfnQDL3IEEtVw2kiPGJ8MANUg0GCRaBk5E3YAGkRUPRYDY0U7RMEUsUlQEGm5+YXFxYA9AH4COw0gA)

Comment: Thanks @T.J, yeah that works, but I wanted to avoid declaring a new type.

Comment: @aminous - Well, technically you can: `const renderHeader: (e: LayoutChangeEvent) => void = ...` but then you have to repeat yourself every time. Declaring a type is simple and has no runtime cost, so why avoid it?